# disk stats in /proc or /sys

Tags: linux, proc

I know there is some data related to partitions and their size in the /proc filesystem. 
What I have not been able to find is the amount of used space (blocks) left on each partition. 
This information seems almost impossible to get.

I want to write a tool that gets the information from either /proc of /sys (both would work).
Is the information (number of used blocks per partition) even avaliable in the /proc or /sys?

If not, does anyone have an idea how to get the number of used blocks in a partition without using any already existing tools, e.g. df or similar?

Comment: The hint for you--->`http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c`.
Also, device IDs can be availed from /proc/self/mountinfo...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've done some digging in the df.c file ... didn't really get most of it. I've not ready any C code in a loong time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syscall that provide the filesystem information. It is called 'statfs' or a modern new call called 'statvfs´

Unfortunately not able to read from /proc.